# Origami-constructible numbers

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, geometric-construction, origami

I apologize if this question has been asked here already; I am wondering whether it is known precisely what is the class of origami-constructible numbers? The class of compass-and-straightedge constructible numbers is the real quadratic closure of the rationals, but it has been shown (e.g. see [here](https://getd.libs.uga.edu/pdfs/lee_hwa-young_201712_ma.pdf)) that the [Huzita-Hatori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huzita%E2%80%93Hatori_axioms) axioms enable construction of all  compass-and-straightedge constructible numbers, and more. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_paper_folding) mentions that using [origami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origami) it is [possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_paper_folding#Doubling_the_cube) to [double the cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube), i.e. $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is constructible, and indeed asserts that all equations up to degree $4$ can be solved using the Huzita-Hatori axioms,  but I cannot access the reference (*Geometric Origami*), and do not know if it is possible to solve even higher order polynomials. It is confirmed [here](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~jking/papers/origami.pdf) that it is possible to solve all cubic equations using origami. [This](https://getd.libs.uga.edu/pdfs/lee_hwa-young_201712_ma.pdf) reference discusses origami-constructible numbers, but does not go beyond roots of cubic equations. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220518/whats-a-minimal-origami-construction-realizing-a-cube-root) question mentions that any number in the real quadratic or cubic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is constructible, but that doesn't imply that this may not be true for the quartic closure as well. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117447/how-well-studied-is-origami-field-theory/3137009#3137009) question doesn't answer my question either; the comments and answer there merely assert that field extensions of degree $2$ and $3$ are origami constructible, and do not address whether higher order extensions are possible, and that question does not address my question of whether there is a class of numbers whose origami-constructibility is open.

My **question** is simple: Is it known what is the class of constructible numbers using the axioms of origami? Is there a class of numbers whose origami-constructibility is open?

Comment: The general solution to a quartic involves only cube and square roots, so if you can solve a cubic and a quadratic you should be able to solve the quartic as well. Not sure if that logic applies if you need to step into $\mathbb{C}$ though

Comment: I'm voting to close this question (a couple of years later, as I find it in a search) as the question is essentially answered by the answer to the linked question: the origami-constructible numbers are exactly those which lie in a tower of quadratic and cubic extensions.